# Excel how to find values in 1 column exist in the range of values in another (approximate)

Tags: excel, countif

How can I search if values in one cell (column A) exist in column B. With an approximate threshhold of +/- .5

For instance:

```
Cell A2: 100.26
Column B: 100.30
```

Is there a formula that can search A2 within all of column B for an approximate match +/- .5 to return true/false?

Comment: Any interest in finding in which rows the "close" values exist ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNTIFS()` for this:

```
 =COUNTIFS(B:B, "<" & A2 + 0.5,B:B, ">" & A2 - 0.5)
```

This tests values in Column B twice. Once to see if there is a value less then A2+.5 and then again to see if that value is also greater than A2 - .5

If you want this to return True/False, just turn it into an inequality:

```
 =COUNTIFS(B:B, "<" & A2 + 0.5,B:B, ">" & A2 - 0.5)>0
```

---

### Update with Example

To show this working, put value `10` in cell A2. Then in B1 though B5 put the following list:

```
1
4
10.2
20
24
```

Now in C1 (or any cell on the same tab that isn't `A2` or in Column `B`) put the formula from above:

```
 =COUNTIFS(B:B, "<" & A2 + 0.5,B:B, ">" & A2 - 0.5)>0
```

And it will spit out "True" because the value `10` that is in cell `A2` is within +/-5 from a value that exists in Column `B`.

[image]

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this forumla to work. How would it be inputted exactly in an table of data shown such as:

a                 b
 18,147.47  7,883.03
 8,603.98  0.00
 3,923.62  9,025.00
 10,612.75  801.19
 260.59          260.59
 1,488.58  1,488.59
 9,025.00  
 611.93  
 189.26  
 7,883.06

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 helper columns C and D where C is `=B1-0.5` and fill down and D is `=B1+0.5` and filled down.

Then `=if(and(a2>C2,a2<D2,TRUE,FALSE)`